# Am I implementing my DAO's correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, dao

I'm going to shorten the real code alot here just to make it quick. I've takin out loads of checks and other stuff just to make it easier to understand.

This is my User class:

```
class User {

    private $userId;
    private $userDAO;

    public function __construct($dbh, $userId) {

        $this->userId = (int) $userId;
        //Create the UserDAO object
        $this->userDAO = new UserDAO($dbh, $this);

        //Get the up to date details of the user
        $userData = $this->userDAO->getUserData()

    }

}
```

And this is my UserDAO class:

```
class UserDAO {

    private $dbh;
    private $user;

    public function __construct($dbh, $user) {

        $this->dbh = $dbh;
        $this->user = $user;

    }

    public function getUserData() {

        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT username FROM " . USERS_TABLE . " WHERE userId = :userId LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bindParam(':userId', $this->user->getUserId(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    }

}
```

Is this the correct way to go about it? As you can see the DAO gets its variables for database queries from the instance of the User class so the DAO methods don't need any arguements.

Should my getUserData() method have an arguement for the userId and use the supplied userId for getting the userdata so that the DAO object does not need to rely on an instance of the User class everytime it needs to get a users data since any userId can be supplied in the methods signature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Providing an object of the class User is called "Dependency Injection" - kinda. From my point of view it's actually a good way to do it. That way you leave it up to your UserDAO class to decide which data to use for the queries.

Though I would use $user as param for the getUserData function, and not via the constructor - But that's probably just my personal preference.

Comment: I was thinking though what if in another class half way through some random method I retrieved a userId and needed to get some of that users details. I would have to create a User object and that would create the UserDAO and that would get the data, set it in User object and I would access it then. I was thinking is that too much work when I could just put a userId arguement in the getUserData() method that would retrieve the data much quicker without having to create a User object. I just thought maybe the UserDAO methods should not work of an instance of the User class and be static methods?

Comment: Of course you're right, it sometimes would be more lightweight to just pass the user id, but it's not necessarily the best or most elegant.

Consider the following: When passing the user object it doesn't matter which values you use in your queries in the dao, so no matter what you change in the dao, it'll work as long the data is contained in the user object and you do not have to change your code besides the UserDAO - But if you just pass the id and you suddenly need the username in your queries, you'll have to change every call of that method and pass the username instead of the id.

Comment: If you're interested in some more information about Dependency Injection: Fabien Potencier wrote an interesting article about it: http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection
(It is however somewhat biased by the approach they used in the symfony2 framework - still very good though)

Answer (score 1):

I see that both User and UserDAO are tightly coupled. User is having UserDAO and UserDAO is having User class.

In DAO Design pattern, its DAO which provide Domain Objects or Transfer Object.

I think better way would be to remove UserDAO from User class and then pass User object to UserDAO class to perform necessary operations.

Comment: But then wouldn't I have to create a new UserDAO object every time I want to do the database work? What about when I create a UserDAO object in a User method and then that method calls another method in the User class and that needs to do some database work wouldn't I have to recreate the UserDAO object in that method again unless the already created UserDAO object is passed to it in its signature? Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: There are two ways to make this better. You introduce Factory class which will create your DAO objects. In factory, you can decide, whether you want to keep once intance, pool of instances or a new instance for every request. Along with this your DAO objects has to be used by Business Layer a.k.a Service Layer. So to perform any operation of User object, your service or business layer should call DAO to perform operation on User.